# Cited references not being printed in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibentry

I am having problems with citations that are correctly being assigned a number in my text now showing up in my bibliography. I am using biblatex with biber and texmaker as my editor.

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

First cite \cite{murata1980reduction}.

Second cite \cite{godefroid1993refining}.

Third cite \cite{cudd}.

\printshorthands
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@article{murata1980reduction,
    title = {{Reduction and Expansion of Live and Safe Marked Graphs}},
    author = {T. Murata and J. Koh},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems},
    pages = {68-71},
    year = {1980},
    volume = {27},
    number= {1},
    note =  {IEEE},
    doi = {10.1109/TCS.1980.1084711}
}

@inproceedings{godefroid1993refining,
    title = {{Refining Dependencies Improves Partial-Order Verification Methods (Extended Abstract)}},
    author = {P. Godefroid},
    booktitle = {Computer Aided Verification},
    year = {1993},
    series = {LNCS},
    volume = {697},
    publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    pages = {438-449},
    doi = {10.1007/3-540-56922-7_36}
}

@misc{cudd,
  title = {{CUDD: CU Decision Diagram Package}},
  author = {F. Somenzi},
  howpublished = {\url{http://web.mit.edu/sage/export/tmp/y/usr/share/doc/polybori/cudd/cuddIntro.html}}
}
```

Compilation result in the following result:

[image]

I have noticed that references using the article entry works fine, but misc and inproceedings does not. How do I make them appear in my bibliography? There are no helpful compilation warnings as far as I can tell.

Comment: You have `type=article` in your `\printbibliography`...

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. My question can be disregarded completely.

Comment: @cgnieder Do you want to type up an answer, or do you want us to close the question as simple typo/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering your references by having `type=article` as argument to `\printbibliography`. Quoting the `biblatex` manual (v3.16 p. 91):

> `type=<entrytype>`
>
> Print only entries whose entry type is `<entrytype>`.
>
> `nottype=<entrytype>`
>
> Print only entries whose entry type is not `<entrytype>`. This option may be used
> multiple times.

Just remove it and you should be fine.